# How destructuring a class methods using proptypes without lose (this) context

Tags: javascript, class, this

i'm wondering if it's possible to destructure the properties/methods from an instance of a class or function while maintaining scope across the destructured variables without having to use call() every time i need that method? For example:

```js
class Pearson {}

Pearson.prototype.speak = function speak(){
  return this.sayHi
};

Pearson.prototype.speakOutLoud = function speakOutLoud(){
  return this.speak().toUpperCase()
};

const pearson = Object.assign(new Pearson(), {sayHi:"hi!!"});

const {speak, speakOutLoud} = pearson;

speak.call(pearson) // hi!!
speakOutLoud.call(pearson) // HI!!
```

I want to avoid the call() and i can't refactor and put all methods inside the class because i have a bunch of them, want to know if exist any cleaver solution to this.

**Solution**:

Bind "this" in the constructor

```
class Pearson {
    constructor(){
        this.speak = this.speak.bind(this)
        this.speakOutLoud = this.speakOutLoud.bind(this)
    }
}

Pearson.prototype.speak = function speak(){
  return this.sayHi
};

Pearson.prototype.speakOutLoud = function speakOutLoud(){
  return this.speak().toUpperCase()
};

const {speak} = Object.assign(new Pearson(), {sayHi:"hi!!"});

speak() // "hi!!"
```

Comment: Put everything into the class itself (don't assign to the prototype afterwards) and use arrow function class fields

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you for your answer, but let suppose I am not allowed to modify the class only to extend it with proptypes, is there any other solution?